# Typescript map specific columns from an array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects and I need a way to allow the user to select which properties they want to import in the database. Is there a way to map and create a separate array only with the properties the user actually wants to send insert.

For example, if we have the following array:

```
[
    {name: 'name1', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
    {name: 'name2', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
    {name: 'name3', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
    {name: 'name4', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
]
```

and the user selects name and phone only, then the array that is sent to be added in the database should look like this:

```
[
        {name: 'name1', phone: '123'},
        {name: 'name2', phone: '123'},
        {name: 'name3', phone: '123'},
        {name: 'name4', phone: '123'},
    ]
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use map and return the new object

```js
const arr = [
    {name: 'name1', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
    {name: 'name2', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
    {name: 'name3', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
    {name: 'name4', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
];

const res = arr.map(({name, phone}) => ({name, phone}));
console.log(res);
```

If you want to make it dynamic with an array of props to copy over

```js
const arr = [
    {name: 'name1', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
    {name: 'name2', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
    {name: 'name3', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
    {name: 'name4', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
];

const copy = ['name', 'phone'];

const res = arr.map(data => copy.reduce((o, k) => (o[k] = data[k], o), {}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use **array.map** function

```js
let arr = [
    {name: 'name1', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
    {name: 'name2', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
    {name: 'name3', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
    {name: 'name4', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
] 


let res = arr.map((x) => {
  return {
    name: x.name,
    phone: x.phone

  }
});

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with computed column values like for example `['name', 'phone']`, You can create a helper function called `pick` to create objects with a subset of all properties:

```js
function pick(props, object) {
    const result = {};
    for (const prop of props) {
        if (prop in object) {
            result[prop] = object[prop];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now you can pass an array of keys, and the source object, and `pick` will return a partial object with only the specified keys:

```js
const object = { name: 'foo', address: 'bar', phone: 'baz' };

console.log(
    pick(['name', 'phone'], object)
);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

function pick(props, object) { const result = {}; for (const prop of props) { if (prop in object) { result[prop] = object[prop]; } } return result; }
```

If you need to do this on an array of objects, use `Array.map` together with `pick` like this:

```js
const arr = [
    {name: 'name1', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
    {name: 'name2', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
    {name: 'name3', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
    {name: 'name4', address: 'addr1', phone: '123'},
];

console.log(
    arr.map((obj) => pick(['name', 'phone'], obj))
);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

function pick(props, object) { const result = {}; for (const prop of props) { if (prop in object) { result[prop] = object[prop]; } } return result; }
```